# Android R /system/bin/ip no longer executable

Tags: android, networking

we've got a feature in our App (TargetSDK = 30), that scans for devices in the current wifi network.
One of the things we do is to call

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ip neigh show")
```

end extract the mac-addresses from stdout.
The code works fine up to Android Q/10, but on a Pixel 2 running Android R/11 the external process quits immediately with exitcode 1 (no exception is thrown)

On the other hand, calling /system/bin/ping runs without any issues.

I checked the Android 11 documentation (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11), but
could'nt find any hint on the new restriction.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: please refer to https://www.programmersought.com/article/59131063032/

Comment: Note that there is no requirement for any particular device model to have any particular command-line binary, let alone in any particular directory.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know that, but the binary is there and can be run from the adb shell without problems

Comment: "but the binary is there" -- on the specific device that you are testing, yes. There are ~2.5 billion Android devices. "I checked the Android 11 documentation" -- on-device command-line binaries are not part of the SDK. Changes there are not going to get documented, in general. "Does anyone have a clue?" -- the ability to identify nearby WiFi devices represents a privacy leak, insofar as you may be able to use that information to identify the device's location. So, they probably just restricted what processes can run that binary.

Comment: @CommonsWare Everything you say is right, but that's not what I asked, you're telling me things I already know. Thanks, though

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 11 (SDK 30)

> In addition, non-privileged apps can't access the device’s MAC
> address; only network interfaces with an IP address are visible. This
> impacts the getifaddrs() and NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()
> methods, as well as sending RTM_GETLINK Netlink messages.
>
> The following is a list of the ways that apps are affected by this
> change:
>
> NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress() returns null for every
> interface. Apps cannot use the bind() function on NETLINK_ROUTE
> sockets.

> **The ip command does not return information about interfaces.**

> Apps cannot send RTM_GETLINK messages. Note that most developers
> should use the higher-level APIs of ConnectivityManager rather than
> lower-level APIs like NetworkInterface, getifaddrs(), or Netlink
> sockets. For example, an app that needs up-to-date information on the
> current routes can get this information by listening for network
> changes using ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback() and
> calling the network's associated LinkProperties.getRoutes().